# Import and using javascript library in backbone.js project

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm newbie to `backbone.js` and `require.js`. Currently I create one backbone project.
Here is `app.js` code :

```
 define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'script',
  'router'

 ], function($, _, Backbone, Script, Router){

 var initialize = function(){
    Router.initialize();
 };

 return {
    initialize: initialize
 };

});
```

Here is `main.js`:

```
require.config({
path: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    script: 'libs/scripts/index'
},

shim:{
    backbone: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
    script: ['jquery'],
    enforceDefine: true
}
});

require([

'app',

], function(App){

App.initialize();

});
```

And the last one is `router.js` :

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'script'
], function($, _, Backbone){

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
      
        '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    }

});

var initialize = function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    app_router('route:defultAction', function(actions){

    });

    Backbone.history.start();
};

 return {
    initialize: initialize
 };
});
```

I want to add [jquery-json library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to my project. If in `html project`, here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.json-2.4.min.js">

</script>
<script>

     function serializeObjToJSON(_obj) {
         var _json = $.toJSON(_obj);
         return _json;
     }

     function deserializeJSONToObj(_json) {
         var _obj = $.evalJSON(_json);
         return _obj;
     }
        
</script>
```

I want to import the library above and using it in my backbone project. But I have no idea how to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your main JS you should add the JSON reference. (put jquery.json-2.4.min.js into lib/ folder)

```
require.config({
path: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    script: 'libs/scripts/index',
    json: 'libs/jquery.json-2.4.min'
}
```

Then you can add it as a definition into the app.js or any other module.js file which is using it in reference .

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'script',
  'router',
  'json'


 ], function($, _, Backbone, Script, Router, Json){

 //Code

 }
```

Then within your js files you have your reference to json. You can call it by using

```
 Json.method()
```

for example.. As soon as you write json, it looks for your definition and then reffers to that lib for the functions you called.

So your index.js or whichever end you want to call it will require something like :

```
define([
      'jquery',
      'underscore',
      'backbone',
      'script',
      'router',
      'json'


     ], function($, _, Backbone, Script, Router, Json){

serializeObjToJSON: function(_obj) {
         var _json = Json.toJSON(_obj);
         return _json;
     }

     deserializeJSONToObj: function(_jsonObject) {
         var _returnObj = Json.evalJSON(_jsonObject);
         return _returnObj;
     }
```

Comment: Do you mean, I have to use `$.Json.toJSON(_obj);` instead of `$.toJSON(_obj);` ?

Comment: You can just reference that library the same way in your router you are referencing 
     `Backbone.history.start();`
This way you would reference the method not in your HTML but in your business end / controller .
     `var returnVar = Json.toJSON(_obj);`

Comment: I want to call it, not in the controller but in the custom js file that I code the global function there. So how should I call it? example in my `index.js` file, located as the above example.

Comment: I added an example with your functions to the Answer.

Comment: OK, then how can I call `serializeObjToJSON` or `deserializeJSONToObj` in my index.html file.

Comment: You dont call it in your HTML file, You pass it through a backbone view if you want to display some data in a dom element.. Im not being rude, but the best policy is to run through some test examples and tutorials to get a good feel for the flowthrough of backbone! http://backbonejs.org/#View

Comment: Yeah, I've been searching it. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar this is a great example intro you should check out.